# MYSQL aggregate sum on two or more tables

Tags: mysql

I need to sum the data from two different columns located in different tables and grouped by commessa

[image]
[image]

I want to sum the column of durata and ore stimate grouped by commessa but when I use SUM function it's counting commessa several times and give me errors.
I tried this:

```
SELECT
c.commessa,
coalesce(SUM(o.durata), 0) AS `SUM(durata)`,
c.macchina,
c.cliente,
c.anno,
c.`tempo previsto`,
c.`tempo previsto`-SUM(o.durata) AS differenza,
c.tipologia,
c.inlinea,
c.stato
e.`ore stimate` AS lavorazioni
FROM orario o
RIGHT OUTER JOIN commessa c using(commessa)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  Select sum(`ore stimate`),
  from `lavorazioni esterne` 
group by commessa
) e using(commessa)
WHERE (c.stato ='APERTA')
GROUP BY c.commessa
```

but i have errors on second left join. Any advices??

Comment: To solve the error on the join, you will need to have `commessa` in your subquery. i.e. `SELECT commessa, SUM(orestimate) FROM table GROUP BY commessa`. You can't join on `commessa` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you for the answer, for sure it was an error. But now i have this one: unknown column 'e.lavorazioni esterne' in 'field list'

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you post the query you are using? `e.lavorazioni esterne` doesn't appear in anywhere in your query so it's not clear how you could get that message.

Comment: please see below

Answer (score 0):

I solved, correct code is:

```
   SELECT
c.commessa,
coalesce(SUM(o.durata), 0) AS `SUM(durata)`,
c.macchina,
c.cliente,
c.anno,
c.`tempo previsto`,
c.`tempo previsto`-SUM(o.durata) AS differenza,
c.tipologia,
c.inlinea,
c.stato,
e.lavorazioni
FROM orario o
RIGHT OUTER JOIN commessa c using(commessa)

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  Select 
commessa,
sum(`ore stimate`) lavorazioni
  from `lavorazioni esterne`
group by commessa
) e on c.commessa=e.commessa


WHERE (c.stato ='APERTA')
GROUP BY c.commessa
```